# Selecting rows and filler (null data)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, null

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ReportID | TeamID | Inning | Runs
1          A        1        3
1          A        2        3
1          A        5        7
1          B        1        3
1          B        3        2
1          B        6        1
```

I need to select all of that data, plus null data for the missing innings.  It also need to stop at the max Inning for both teams (i.e. teamB's highest inning is 6, so I would collect 6 rows for both teamA and teamB yielding 12 total rows.)

For a visual, I need the output of the query to look like this:

```
ReportID | TeamID | Inning | Runs
1          A        1        3
1          A        2        3
1          A        3        NULL
1          A        4        NULL
1          A        5        7
1          A        6        NULL
1          B        1        3
1          B        2        NULL
1          B        3        2
1          B        4        NULL
1          B        5        NULL
1          B        6        1
```

Is there anyway to do this with just a query?  Modifying the original table to add the null values is not an option.

Comment: Left join to a [numbers table](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/you-require-a-numbers-table.aspx). Numbers tables will save your life homie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self join to generate the permutations of reports and teams
Left self join to generate hits which might be nullable.

This is probably a lot more efficient if it's done outside of SQL

```
SELECT ins.ReportID, teams.TeamID, ins.inning, score.Runs
FROM games as ins
JOIN games AS teams
    ON ins.ReportID = teams.ReportID
LEFT JOIN games AS score
    ON ins.ReportID = score.ReportID
    AND teams.TeamID = score.TeamID
    AND ins.inning = score.inning
GROUP BY ins.ReportID, teams.TeamID, ins.inning;
```

Comment: Close! This returns some null data, but it misses the innings which are missing for both teams.

Comment: If a game is played and there are no innings, was it really a game?
Change the JOIN games AS teams to a left join and I think you'll have that.  Though I'm not sure what the result would mean.

Comment: As much as I agree, this is what the client has asked for (and you really can't argue when the client is with the MLB ughh).  In any case, I've decided to just write a web service call to handle this.